# google cloud storage issue

Tags: android, google-cloud-storage

I am using google cloud storage to store images on android..I created project in `google developers console` and gave all id's from that project.

```
private static final String PROJECT_ID_PROPERTY =  "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";      //project ID
private static final String APPLICATION_NAME_PROPERTY = "refined";   //application name, can be any
private static final String ACCOUNT_ID_PROPERTY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-n5kqcd842faki0se7s82vpcf9l1rbvui@developer.gserviceaccount.com"; //user account email
```

Downloaded `P12` file and accessing from the code for setting `p12 key`.

When I tried on 2 days back , images got uploaded correctly and I could see them in the browser..But when I try today the same code, it is giving forbidded issue.

```
{"code":403,"errors":    [{"domain":"global","message":"Forbidden","reason":"forbidden"}],"message":"Forbidden"}
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: If that code with that key was working a couple days ago and stopped, is it possible you've deleted those credentials on the console page?

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the issue...Issue was with permissions...
I gave write permissions on the bucket for the client ID, then it is working now.

Thanks for all